# Which HF transceivers feature a built-in Ethernet port for remote operation?

Tags: hf, transceiver, internet, remote-control

I would like to compile a list of HF transceivers that feature an Ethernet port (RJ45) for remote internet operation.
It would also be interesting to add the supported operating system(s) for remote operation in this list (Microsoft Windows, Mac OSX, GNU/Linux, Android, ...).

Finding this information on the net via a search engine is difficult because the word "transceiver" is abundantly used in the context of Ethernet chip design.

Furthermore, only few HF transceivers currently feature an Ethernet port. Compiling a list here in the form of **one answer per model** would help as a future buying guide for the hams with an interest in remote operation.

Comment: List-format questions [aren't really suitable for the Q&A format of StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki) - the number of answers are typically unbounded, and are often likely to change over time.

Comment: @Amber If have seen many list questions and answers on other SE site that worked and keep on working very well. [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49414/26348) is a nice example. However, we better discuss this issue on [meta](http://meta.ham.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Here's the relevant meta question: http://meta.ham.stackexchange.com/questions/12/how-about-list-questions

Answer (score 1):

Ten-Tec [Omni VII HF+6m Transceiver](http://www.tentec.com/omni-vii-hf-6m-transceiver/) supports MS Windows. The remote GUI program can be downloaded [here](http://www.rfsquared.com/). I do not know about Mac OSX or GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The not yet commercialised FlexRadio [FLEX-6000 series](http://www.flexradio.com/FLEX-6000_v2.pdf) is said to be going to offer OS-independent remote operation.